# Hex Colors - How to Calculate from 1 Color to Another

Tags: css, hex, less

I work on .LESS and I am looking for a method how calculate from a hex color to another.
For example: I have #000000, then I do some calculations (lighten, or darken, or mix...) somehow finally it will become #657177.

Let's say:
@header-background:    #000000;
@tags:                 lighten(@header-background, 30%);

I have tried many percentage numbers, but I couldn't get exactly from #000000 to #657177.

Please give a hand.
Thanks!

Comment: can you edit the rgb values 65 71 77 independently and that would treat the separate colors independently?

Comment: Actually, #000000 is a primary color and anything else should be based on calculations to get a secondary color.

Comment: What you are implying is that 30% lighter #000000 should be #657177.
I plug in the number to w3schools.com color picker and get that #657177 is 43%.
Maybe your numbers are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp since you know what color you are looking for, and it can give you the percentage difference.

Comment: Thank you, Musselman very much for your help!  I try to create a dynamic color theme.  If a primary color is changed, every color else will be changed, accordingly.